# Missing Chaptername in Header with fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I changed my fancyhdr settings, but it doesn't look as I want to.
Just look at my example below and use pdflatex. On the second side of the pdf, the headers text should be: "Chapter 1: MyChaptername"

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{myheader}{ 
    \fancyhead{} %clear all headers
    \fancyfoot{} %clear all footers
    \fancyhead[L]{\chaptername \ \thechapter: } %How to insert the Chapter names like "MyChapter"?
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} 
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}    
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{myheader}

\chapter{MyChaptername}
This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... 
This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... 
This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... 
This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... 
This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is  

\subsection{MySubsection}
This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... 
This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... 
This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... 
This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... This is some Text... 
\end{document}
```

Can anybody help me please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use

```
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
```

and redefine `\chaptermark`

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter:\ #1}{}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{myheader}{
    \fancyhead{} %clear all headers
    \fancyfoot{} %clear all footers
    \fancyhead[L]{\leftmark} %How to insert the Chapter names like "MyChapter"?
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}
}
\pagestyle{myheader}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter:\ #1}{}}

\usepackage{lipsum} %for dummy text

\begin{document}   
\chapter{MyChaptername}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Wow, that works pretty fine! Thank you!
Well I didn't understand what \leftmark does and how it works.

Comment: @Lukas You're welcome. The command `\chaptermark` issues a `\markboth` command which defines a `\leftmark` command with that contents.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This evening I'm gonna sign up. Then I will vote you answer up!